# Object in array within array to string

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array with arrays. I do:

```
predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@",temphref];
        NSArray *results = [shareArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

And if I print

> (
>           (
>           "id=77",
>           "path=/cp012725.exe",
>           "share_type=3",
>           "token=88ae683504def4caab9154f1684dccdf"
>       ) )

I would like to get these Array values into strings. `stringForID` `stringForPath` `stringForShareType`
`stringForToken`

I try to just `NSString *stringForID = results[0][0];`

But it fails when the array is empty, but array does not respond to `if(results==nil)`

if I print the `results`when there are none, it prints `()`so its not `nil` i guess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why did you tag this with "basic" (which is for the BASIC programming language)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter will always return an array, even if its empty, change your if statement from...

```
if(results==nil)
```

to this

```
if(results.count == 0)
```

Comment: Super, works now. thanks! Array within an array within an array.